# Exchange 2013 and Exchange 2010 coexistence open another mailbox issue with outlook web app

Tags: exchange

When we logon to outlook web app with a user on exchange 2013 or 2010 everything works fine. When we open another mailbox from there once logged on that recites on exchange 2013 the mailbox opens fine when we open another mailbox that is on exchange we get the following error:

The custom error module does not recognize this error. Can anyone explain why this happens.

Kind regards,

Litrick

Comment: We changed the client access dns to exchange 2013. When we logon to outlook web app with a user on exchange 2013 or 2010 everything works fine (Proxy works fine). But the problem is once you are logged on to outlook web app with a mailbox on exchange 2013 or 2010 and you want to open a mailbox on 2010 with the option "Open another mailbox" you get this message "The custom error module does not recognize this error", when you chose the option "open another mailbox" and you fill in a mailbox on exchange 2013 it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear which way you are going. Are you starting in Exchange 2013 and opening a mailbox on 2010, or starting on 2010 and opening a mailbox on 2013? 
Does the URL change in the browser to reflect the server change?

Simon.